# Converting java.sql.Date to java.util.Date

Tags: java, jdbc

What's the simplest way to convert a java.sql.Date object to a java.util.Date while retaining the timestamp?

I tried:

```
java.util.Date newDate = new Date(result.getDate("VALUEDATE").getTime());
```

with no luck. It's still only storing the date portion into the variable.

Comment: This inheritance is a weird design legacy

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The class java.sql.Date is designed to carry only a date without time, so the conversion result you see is correct for this type. You need to use a java.sql.Timestamp to get a full date with time.

```
java.util.Date newDate = result.getTimestamp("VALUEDATE");
```

Comment: I'll try this then:
new Date(result.getTimestamp("VALUEDATE").getTime());

Comment: this should work, but since `java.sql.Timestamp` also derives from `java.util.Date` you could as well just use the Timestamp instance.

Answer (score 20):

If you really want the runtime type to be util.Date then just do this:

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date(sqlDate.getTime());
```

Brian.

Comment: @PlexQ : It should if your sqlDate is null, but perhaps I'm missing something obvious as you appear to have used a lot of exclamation marks.

Answer (score 9):

Since `java.sql.Date` extends `java.util.Date`, you should be able to do

```
java.util.Date newDate = result.getDate("VALUEDATE");
```

Comment: Yes, but in runtime, `newDate` will still be an instance of `java.sql.Date`

Comment: it's true what @joeybaruch says, and there if you try the .toInstant() method you'll get an UnsopportedMethodException, so it's not recommended

Answer (score 7):

This function will return a converted java date from SQL date object.

```
public static java.util.Date convertFromSQLDateToJAVADate(
            java.sql.Date sqlDate) {
        java.util.Date javaDate = null;
        if (sqlDate != null) {
            javaDate = new Date(sqlDate.getTime());
        }
        return javaDate;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

From reading the source code, if a `java.sql.Date` does actually have time information, calling `getTime()` will return a value that includes the time information.

If that is not working, then the information is not in the `java.sql.Date` object.  I expect that the JDBC drivers or the database is (in effect) zeroing the time component ... or the information wasn't there in the first place.

I think you should be using `java.sql.Timestamp` and the corresponding resultset methods, and the corresponding SQL type.

Comment: I'm querying against Oracle 10g. Using ojdbc14.jar

Answer (score -2):

In the recent implementation, java.sql.Data is an subclass of java.util.Date, so no converting needed.
see here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html