# Java parsing String to a Date returns incorrect Date

Tags: java, jdbc

I am storing my 2 Java date types as Date and Time for a MySQL database table. I am using the `SimepleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd")` to store the date in my database and it shows up as the correct date when i go to select it. However when i try to parse it back into a util.Date and create a new Event Object, it shows up as `30/12/2012` instead of `31/05/2013` as it is in the database. The time, when parsed into a util.Date and formatted prints out correctly. I am not sure why the Date is printing the wrong date, but the time is printing the correct time.

Database

```
+--------+--------------+-----------+
+ EVENT1 +  2013-05-31  +  02:30:00 +
+--------+--------------+-----------+
+ EVENT2 +  2013-05-31  +  01:00:00 +
+--------+--------------+-----------+
```

Prints:

```
Event1
30/12/2012
02:30
Event2
30/12/2012
01:00
```

Comment: this could be due to mismatch between data types between DB and Java.what is your column data type in MySQL.. if it is date then use rs.getDate() instaed of rs.getString()..

Comment: `getDate` returns a `java.sql.Date` which already extends `java.util.Date`

Comment: let me answer this question...pls see my answer

Comment: @Pavan Kumar K, i don't see your question. but i gave your comment an upvote.

Comment: please see my answer for this question... that should work out for you

Answer (score 4):

It should be `yyyy-MM-dd` with lower case Ys. See here for what the capital Y means...

[Y returns 2012 while y returns 2011 in SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686331/y-returns-2012-while-y-returns-2011-in-simpledateformat)

Comment: This solved it for some reason. I changed dateFormat to `yyyy-MM-dd` and it returned the correct Date (31/05/2013). Its strange because I used `YYYY-MM-dd` to INSERT the date into the database and it stored it as 31/05/2013 as well.....:\.

Comment: @user1352609 You can't expect development language (Java) and your DB to use the same patterns. YYYY is working with your DB but hasn't the same meaning than in Java

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is wrong. (mm != MM, yyyy != YYYY ...)

Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

The proper method is `rs.getDate(int)`. Take a look at
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate(int)

With that method you get a `java.sql.Date` and if you want to transform it to a `java.util.Date` take a look at this [Converting java.sql.Date to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066335/converting-java-sql-date-to-java-util-date)

You can even do this

```
Date date =  rs.getTimestamp(2);
```

By the way, is better to have your date object independent on the format you want to use to show it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
String testDate = "2007-11-02T14:46:03";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
Date date = formatter.parse(testDate);
```

But better way to store in database is to use timestamp instead of storing date and time separately

Answer (score -1):

try this...

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");   
Date date =  dateFormat.parse(rs.getDate(2).toString());
```

Comment: -1, this makes no sense, you already have a Date (a `java.sql.Date` which is a subclass of `java.util.Date`)