# How to set search condition of date, to retrieve other details on that date from database?

Tags: java, database, swing, date, java.util.date

These are the basic conditions set in my code.

```
t1 = new JFormattedTextField(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"));
t1.setValue(new java.util.Date());
java.util.Date searchDate=(java.util.Date)t1.getValue();
```

Retrieving Date from the Result Set.

```
Date Date1 = rs.getDate("Date1");
```

I wanted to know whether this condition for matching the dates i enter and for retrieving the dates from database is correct or not. I am new in the world of coding.

```
if(new java.sql.Date(searchDate.getTime()).equals(Date1))
{
... //code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind...

making it...

```
java.sql.Date sqlSearchdate = new java.sql.Date(searchDate.getTime());
```

and

```
if(sqlSearchdate.equals(Date1)
{
...
}
```

solved the problem. This was so silly. My bad for asking such a question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that should work, according to http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/ though i'm not sure why you're creating a new Date object in the if statement.

Comment: for retrieving other values from table on that date, both are different dates, the date i input in textfield is java.util.date and the date i get from database is java.sql.date.

Comment: May want to look here, then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066335/converting-java-sql-date-to-java-util-date