# how to convert the SQL date type to Java param

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have a field in sql table of type date with value 1944-01-02. Now I am writing a java function which will pull this data from the database and use it as a java method param. How should I handle it?

method looks like this:

```
void search(Date date);
```

I want to put 1944-01-02 in to the method param, but java complier complain does not matter if I import `java.util.date` or `java.sql.date`.

Comment: `but java complier complain` can you please be more specific?

Comment: You get a ResultSet and then the date from it? In this case it will be a java.sql.Date (which strips hours, minutes, seconds and mili seconds)

Comment: I think it would be better to use java.time.LocalDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert your sql date to java date:

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date(sqlDate.getTime());
```

Get more info about this at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066335/converting-java-sql-date-to-java-util-date)

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this:

```
search(Date.valueOf("1944-01-02"));
```

Format: yyyy-[m]m-[d]d