# Date toString() method returns different strings

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am querying data from database using 'JdbcTemplate' spring bean. The returned object contains a data field. The problem I am facing is when I console print `returnedObject.getDate().toString()` it returns "2017-08-04", but when I do `new Date().toString()` then it returns `Mon Mar 25 17:36:32 GMT 2019`. I have read that java `Date` class does not contain any format in it and to format any `Date` we use `SimpleDateFormat` class. So my question is what parameter in `Date` object is causing it to print in different formats and how do I change its behaviour ?

Comment: Check the `toString()` method implemented by class of object returned by `returnedObject.getDate()` Most likely, `java.util.Date` is not same as class returned by `returnedObject.getDate()` hence both are returning two different formats.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi it is a java.util Date field

Comment: Class return by `returnedObject.getDate()` should be `java.sql.Date` where as `new Date()` class is `java.util.Date` and as both are different hence the `toString()` for both will be different.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated (and the `java.sql.Date` correctly mentioned in some answers makes it even worse). Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDBCTemplate is returning a `java.sql.Date` instance which extends `java.util.Date`. The [JavaDocs of that `toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString--) implementation explain the used date format:

> Formats a date in the date escape format yyyy-mm-dd.

The [`toString()` implementation of `java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--) uses a longer date-time format:

> Converts this Date object to a String of the form:
>   `dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy`

The type of your date field could be `Object` and you could still assign a `java.sql.Date` or any subclass to the field. It's the runtime class of the variable that determines the behavior through dynamic method dispatch, i.e. which `toString()` implementation gets invoked.

If you want to convert the subclass to a "plain" `java.util.Date` instance, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066335/converting-java-sql-date-to-java-util-date). Note that the time part will always be omitted from an SQL `DATE`. If you need that information, you should use `TIMESTAMP` instead.

Comment: that field variable's type is indeed java.util.Date and it gets set in my `customObjects` builder by fetching date from  `ResultSet` from custom `ResultSetExtractor`.

Comment: So, did this answer your question or do you have further concerns?

Comment: no, I am still not convinced why that field of type `java.util.Date` prints in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.

Comment: Because that's how inheritance works. The type of the field could be `Object` and you could still assign a `java.sql.Date` or any subclass to the field. It's the _runtime class_ of the variable that determines the behavior through dynamic method dispatch.

Comment: perfect ! if you add above comment in your answer I will accept your answer. Sadly I wasted half of the day for such a small thing, I should have thought a little more.

Answer (score 1):

> when I console print returnedObject.getDate().toString() it returns
>   "2017-08-04", but when I do new Date().toString() then it returns Mon
>   Mar 25 17:36:32 GMT 2019

That's simple.

The `returnedObject.getDate()` code returns an object of `java.sql.Date` type whereas most likely the `Date` class in your second case is `java.util.Date`.

As per the [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString--) of `java.sql.Date`, its `toString` method returns a String in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

And as per the [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--) of `java.util.Date`, its `toString` method returns a String in `dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy` format.

Answer (score 0):

Although the Date class is intended to reflect coordinated universal time (UTC), it may not do so exactly, depending on the host environment of the Java Virtual Machine, according to the Java documentation of the date class. I think that means that it is looking at the your system's date format while the SQL query comes with the UTC format. There is not date parameter that changes the format. You need to apply it like you said via the date formater.Look at the DateFormater class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html
Particularly the format method.

Answer (score 0):

`java.sql.Date` extends `java.util.Date`.  You can get both sorts of dates in ms since 1970 using getTime() and setTime(long time) can be used to create identical types, so you can get the string in whatever format you like.

However, note that  Java's old date classes are garbage (not thread safe, not immutable, and poorly named (they are timestamps not dates).

There are 3rd party libraries that are superior.  Look at java.util.time which is the new way to do it.